# Ubuntu 14.04 not detecting allocated partition on windows 8.1 laptop

Tags: dual-boot

I've  brought new Lenovo Z5070 laptop with preinstalled FreeDOS. Afterward, I've installed Windows 8.1 on it with Legacy BIOS enabled.

I have to use Ubuntu in dual boot with it. I've shrink my `C:` partition with 30GB to install Ubuntu in the freed space.

When installing Ubuntu, the installer is not detecting the new partition. It shows the entire as `1TB HDD`.

I've stopped fast boot in Windows. It's installed in legacy mode so there is no secure boot option.
I want to know which point I'm getting wrong.

Comment: Post this: `sudo parted -l` from terminal in live installer. Since Windows is in legacy mode, you must install Ubuntu in Legacy/BIOS/CSM mode not UEFI. Best to use Something Else. How you boot installer UEFI or BIOS is how it installs. If booted & installed in UEFI mode you will erase Windows with conversion to gpt partitioning. http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Comment: hey Thanks for the reply,
i tried with legacy mode and select try Ubuntu during installation but still Ubuntu not detecting my previews installed windows 8.1 and it shows entire 1TB HDD!

Comment: Even with Something Else install option? Can you just partition / as ext4 and swap with gparted and then use Something Else to choose those partitions you have created in advance. Or have you used all 4 primary partitions that MBR(msdos) allows? The parted list will show existing partitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully installed Ubuntu 14.04 in dual boot!
There are several steps that I followed here:

1. As I told you I have a disk with an MBR partition, but boot repair detected them as GPT.
   Actually that was stray GPT which may remain from a previously installed OS. That's why to wipe out them I used FixParts software with live Ubuntu and used the tutorial as described here: http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/.
2. Afterward, I tried to install Ubuntu but my allocated space was detected as "unusable space" rather then "free space" during the installation, because with an MBR disk we can do a maximum of 4 partitions and the drive that I shrank was C: having a primary partition!
   That's why I shrank D: drive having a logical partition with 30GB and installed Ubuntu in Legacy mode.
3. After successfully installing Ubuntu I restarted my laptop, but I was not able to detect Windows 8.1 (all my data remained safe as it was earlier in Windows!)
   so in the terminal I ran the command: `sudo update-grub` and... it detected Windows 8.1. After restarting the laptop I got an option to select either of the two OSs.  :)